# What does "Failed to get composer template data" mean in Facebook lint?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've created a trivial prototype app on Facebook. When my test script (JavaScript on Ubuntu command line, powered by Node.js) tries to access the app, it produces this error message:

```
{ error:
   { message: 'Invalid OAuth access token.',
     type: 'OAuthException',
     code: 190
   }
}
```

So I'm trying to debug using Facebook's lint debugger. However when I paste the app's access token into lint, it responds with:

`Failed to get composer template data.`

I have no idea what this means, and a lengthy stumble through Google reveals page after page of people who are similarly clueless.

Has anyone seen this error, and fixed it?

Details about the app:

It's configured to ask for read_insights and manage_pages alongside standard permissions. No other permissions are requested.

Settings, Basic: I've had to put a nonexistent URL in the secure canvas URL, since I don't have any SSL hosting anywhere. The non-SSL canvas URL is complete and points to an existing page.

"App Info" is all filled in (apart from Tagline which is optional).

I haven't submitted the app for approval for public use, and there are no "items for approval". I'm going to be the only person who ever uses it, this isn't necessary for this app.

Switching from "live" to "sandbox" and back again doesn't make any difference.

There are no warnings anywhere on the app developer page.

Answer (score 7):

A client I worked for was experiencing a similar issue - when sharing certain URLs on Facebook, the Facebook Sharer wasn't picking up any of the thumbnails. Frustrated with that, the client was trying to clear the Sharer's cache using the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, hoping that this way Facebook will re-cache the page and display the corresponding images.

However, in doing so, the client was seeing the ambiguous "Failed to get composer template data." error, and resorted to me for a solution.

I did my research, and it turned out that Facebook had decided to block the domain of the CDN that my client was using to serve images from. Since the pages were loading all images from that CDN, none of the images were getting picked up and the debugger was returning that "Failed to get composer template data." error.

The moment we started serving the images from a new CDN, Facebook started picking them up correctly, and the error disappeared.

Hope that helps you!

P.S. Please note however, this is not a permanent solution if you are violating Facebook's terms in some way. Yes - Facebook's spam prevention algorithms do return false positives sometimes, but most of the time they have a pretty good reason to block your content.

P.P.S. Worth noting, in the case I'm describing, when we passed the CDN URL to the debugger, it returned "This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know."

Comment: I received the error when trying to make an ImageShack image I uploaded the og:share image. So apparently Facebook blacklists ImageShack.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, "Failed to get composer template data.".

I believe my path to Images was blacklisted by Facebook. Workaround was to create virtual path that points to Images folder. Then I could reference /Images with /OGImages virtual directory. Then I no longer received the error.

Answer (score 0):

Had kind of the same problem, I figured out I needed to use HTTPS instead of HTTP for the image link, and everything went fine then.

Hope it may help !

Answer (score 0):

I had just the same problem and it appeared suddenly after several months without any site changes except content. First I thought the Facebook spam filter had blocked our site, as suggested by a [Ycombinator comment thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7807315) but then I found the real problem.

In fact it was the **official Facebook Wordpress plugin** that was acting up. Disabling it meant that the Facebook debugger could once again fetch our data and sharing started to work immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case is was a "Facebook Share Buttons" plugin for Wordpress. I've deactivated the plugin and resolved the issue.