# Failed to get composer template data. blacklisted?

Tags: facebook

URLs to our app https://makesense.org doesn't display nice on facebook anymore ( ex: https://beta.makesense.org/challenges/763 )

The Open Graph Object Debugger show an "Failed to get composer template data." error.

[image: debugger error]

I updated all our API calls to Graph 2.0 but the problem is still there.

I also read on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636903/what-does-failed-to-get-composer-template-data-mean-in-facebook-lint) that I could come from our CDN ( s3 bucket ) that is blacklisted. So I copied the bucket form `makesense-production` to `makesense` but it is still not working.

Facebook does scrap and update our `make-sense:challenge` objects, it is just refusing to display the content...

Here is an example of scraped but not displayed page https://beta.makesense.org/challenges/763 that has https://graph.facebook.com/887885094602305 for facebook object.

I wonder if facebook did blacklisted our website.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue or to contact facebook support ?

Comment: Is your server live? It seems that the crawler is failing to connect to your server. There is also currently an open bug report about share data not displaying correctly https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/ which may be related to your issue.

Comment: Hello, yes the server is live. For example this URL http://beta.makesense.org/challenges/797 return "Failed to get composer template data." error.

Comment: It seems that one of your URLs may still blocked, maybe one of your image files going by the fact that you can still post the URL on Facebook directly but no link preview loads. You can report this here: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151